# Is taking pictures allowed in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, photos

I have heard people say that taking pictures is not allowed in Islam. I want to know if its true? With references
Random pictures to keep as memories.

Answer (score -5):

what kind of picture?
i have seen picture's in all kind except nudity in all Muslim countries and pictures taken from every kind of Muslim cleric...
the only ban is on nudity and sex advertising photography...

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE i'd recommend you to make take the toou http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour and read how to answer a Question http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. We like Answers here to have a reference not only a comment!